# Windows Simple MIDI Synthesizer?

Tags: windows, midi

I am looking for a small MIDI synthesizer for Windows. It must accept MIDI notes from MIDI ports. On Mac I've found this

http://notahat.com/simplesynth/

which works nicely. Anything for Windows?

**Note:** I'm looking for something free and compact, so how it sounds is not important in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [CoolSoft's VirtualMidiSynth](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth).

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know of a freeware all-in-one synth for Windows, you could roll one yourself by using [Tobybear's MiniHost](http://tobybear.de/p_minihost.html) together with a [free VST plugin](http://www.kvraudio.com/get.php), such as [Oatmeal](http://www.kvraudio.com/get/2237.html).

It's been awhile since I used MiniHost, but I recall that it can interface with the system MIDI ports, and that you can also instruct it to automatically reload the last plugin on startup.  This way, you get a standalone synth without the hassle of a sequencer.

Comment: Thanks Nik, really to avoid more work here. I'm creating an iPad app that talks to a Java app. I just want to synth to be able to demonstrate how the thing works. Are there any free DAWs that come with synths for Windows?

Comment: @Yar, not sure about any that come with synths, but reaper.fm is at least free for windows.  But like I said, there's a ton of great, free VST synths out there... it's really not so much work as you think.

Comment: Updated link for MiniHost: https://tobybear.de/files.html